# Comparing a Particular String with another string (multiple values) via Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL to Compare one string among multiple values in another string .

Example : I have 2 string as following. In `first_string="B"` and in `second_string="A,B,C,D,E".`

How do i compare first_string against individual value of second_string?

IF the value of the First String is among the values of Second string then i need to proceed with the further actions.

Comment: `where ',' || second_string || ',' like '%,' || first_string || ',%'`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this using strings, you can use `like`:

```
where ',' || second_string || ',' like '%,' || first_string || ',%'
```

However, I would suggest that you investigate alternatives to storing such values in strings.  Tables (including nested tables) are a better choice.  You can also use JSON and similar formats.